# Calculating quartiles of a given PDF

Tags: statistics, percentile

I am supposed to calculate the quartiles ( 25th, 50th, 75th percentile ) of the PDF -

f(x) = x*( 2 - e^(-2) )     if   0 < x < 1

f(x) = e^(-2x)              if   x  ≥  1

How should I go about solving this? Should I convert the PDF into a CDF?

Comment: Can you integrate $f(x)$ between $0$ and $1$? See what happens when you get the result.

Comment: The simple answer is yes, knowing the CDF will enable you to answer the question.  @TobyMak's comment is that you only need to actually find it for the first piece since $P(0\le X \le 1) > 0.75$

Comment: integrating f(x) between 0 and 1 gives me \frac{2e^2-1}{2e^2}.  @TobyMak
how do I proceed from here?

Comment: As Henry said, $\frac{2e^2-1}{2e^2} > 0.75$. Now go back to the CDF and find which values of $x$ give $0.25, 0.5, 0.75$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm confused. Why is \frac{2e^2-1}{2e^2}\ > 0.75 ? Also, my CDF looks like this - 

f(x) = 0 for x<0 
f(x) = (x*( 2 - e^(-2) ) for 0<x<1
f(x) = 1 for x≥1

shouldn't 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 all lie btwn 0<x<1? @TobyMak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst a CDF makes the problem easier, you can just integrate the function from $0$ to some unknown upper bound, where you let the integral be equal to the percentile. For example, if we are integrating a PDF, say $f(x)$, looking to find what the $75^{th}$ percentile is, we can say.

$\int_0^a f(x).dx = 0.75$

Where we now can solve for $a$